# iOS endoscope camera connection

Tags: ios, camera, external-accessory

I am currently trying to connect a wifi endoscope camera to my app in objective c.
I tried connecting using ExternalAccessory, but it registers no accessory.

Has anyone got an idea on how I can do this.

If it is not possible does anyone know of a wired version?

Comment: You would need to refer to any documentation available from the device manufacturer. If it is wifi then you probably just need to open a tcp connection to a specific port on the device and stream the vision

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for your reply, it didn't come with any docs. The TCP connection how would i know the port from the wifi box?

Comment: WiFi Camera? Did you try to search simply for it? Like Using Safari.app? Can you do it on your Mac? Is there a doc? Is it mpeg video?